# DataTable select method not returning any value

Tags: c#, select, datatable, ado.net

i want to check if value in datatable exists or not based on the the value of switch expression.
First i have loaded datatable from database.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select mainMenuNum, subMenuData from [menudatas] where ivrNumber = '" + number + "';", objConnection);
 SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(dataReader);
```

here in the case 2 i am checking if record exists in datatable based on the value of switch expression. But it is not working.

```
switch (number)
  {
     case 0: TextToSpeech("No information on 0 button"); break;
     case 1: TextToSpeech("Hello"); break;
     case 2:
          {
             DataRow[] result = dt.Select("subMenuData where mainMenuNum = '" +number + "'");
             if (result != null)
                  { LowerMenu();
                    break;
                  }

             else
                 {

                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select mainMenuData from [menudatas] WHERE mainMenuNum = '" + number + "' AND ivrNumber = '" + number + "'; ", objConnection);
                  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                  while (dr.Read())
                  {
                    data = dr.GetString(0);
                  }

                   dr.Close();
                   data1 = data;
                   objConnection.Close();
                   TextToSpeech(data1); break;
                 }
         }
  }
```

Please help me out in this matter.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the WHERE condition without the WHERE keyword or any other info

```
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("mainMenuNum = '" +number + "'");
```

At this point the result array contains the rows that matches the criteria for the filter. You could check the content of the row with

```
// Check if the result contains at least one row    
if(result.Length > 0)
{
   ....

   // if your logic requires another check on the returned columns you 
   // could add it to the Select expression above or just add a check here
   // Here an example with a column of string type
   if(result[0].Field<string>("YourColumnName") == "value")
     ....     

   ....
}
```

You could find the rules for the expression to use in the `Select` method in the [DataColumn.Expression property page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: but i want to check value from another column based on this where condition

Comment: Then you have the datarow at index zero to look at the field value

Comment: sorry i didn't understand it. can u explain

Comment: I mean, the Select method filters the DataTable rows and returns the rows that match the criteria. If you want to add another condition on another column you could add to your filter the AND operator **IE: _Select(col1=value1 AND col2=value2)_** and so on. Otherwise if you want just one criteria in Select but then you need to look at values on other column you could simply use the syntax **_if(result[0]["ColumnName"] == valuetolookfor)_**